# How to push a snapshot to a remote repository?

Tags: git, android-studio

Sorry for this rudimentary question, but I have spent a lot of time searching for the answer online.
I thought my scenario was simple and typical:

1. An Android project Foo in Android Studio set up for GIT.
2. A remote GIT server on a computer using Bonobo and repository Foo was created
3. Added the remote repository (http://computername/Bonobo.Git.Server/Foo.git) to the project.

After Push, only a few files out of hundreds have been pushed to the remote repository. What I want is for the remote repository to have all the project files so that one can clone a copy of the project from the repository.
I must be missing something very simple and fundamental.  I have been using SVN for a long time, and just started trying GIT.

Any tip will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are a number of things which could have gone wrong here. Is the remote repository a bare repository? If so, that repo will only contain git's internal files, not a working copy that you can actually browse. You'll need to the remote to see that. There's also the possibility that you didn't push what you thought you did.

Comment: It would be a lot easier for us to help if you explained in more detail what steps you took to set up the remote repository, add the remote, commit your files, and perform the push. Also, what unexpected result you're seeing on the remote? You mentioned missing files, but I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. What happens when you clone the remote?

Comment: git doesn't push files, at all. git pushes _commits_ a named entity with a given filetree, author, commit message and other attributes. So if you don't see any file on a remote server after push, then quite likely they're missing in commit. Add missing files to the index, amend the commit or make another one, make sure, that all files are on their place _inside the commit_ , then push.

Comment: Thank you all for prompt responses. IMHO, Bonobo GIT Server is a fantastic one and extremely easy to use.  I created the remote repository by clicking button "Create new repository" and give a name, then use the URL provided Bonobo to configure remote for the project. @user3159253: You probably touched something of which I lack thorough understanding. I migrated the project from Eclipse to Android Studio and changed VCS from SVN to GIT.  I noticed at the very beginning that GIT only commits changed files.  How can I commit all files at first, then only changes afterwards.

Comment: @Hong since Android Studio is based on IntelliJ Idea, I hope that recipes for Idea would work. So [here is](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/adding-files-to-a-local-git-repository.html) the tutorial on how to add files to the index and here's [the rest](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-git-integration.html) of the docs. Hope it helps

Comment: @user3159253  Thank you! That did it. Could you turn your comment to an answer so that I can accept it.  Now I have finally felt that I am getting the hang of GIT in Android Studio. After setting up GIT, no files are versioned, so the GIT repository is empty. Every time a file is changed, AD will ask you to change it to versioned. In my case of migrating a project, all files should be added to the versioned pool immediately after GIT is set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git doesn't push files, at all. git pushes *commits*: named entities, each with a given filetree, author, commit message and other attributes. So if you don't see expected files on a remote server after `git push`, then quite likely these files were missing in commit.

Add missing files to the index, amend the commit or make a new one, make sure, that all files are on their place *inside the commit* , and only then push

Since Android Studio is based on IntelliJ Idea, I hope that recipes for Idea would work. So here is [the tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/adding-files-to-a-local-git-repository.html) on how to add files to the index and here's [the rest](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-git-integration.html) of the docs.